# XNA intersect/collision with multiple classes?

Tags: c#, xna, collision, intersect

For the past 12 hours I've been trying "all" different methods I can think of, in order to make two rectangles intersect/test collision correctly in XNA (4.0).

I have three classes (just example names):

- Game1.cs
- Player.cs
- Man.cs

In Game1 I load the content like this:

**// In the beginning of Game1:**

```
    Player player;
    Man man;
```

**// LoadContent:**

```
    man = new Man(Content.Load<Texture2D>("ManImage"), new Rectangle(440, 310, 150, 98));
    player = new Player(Content.Load<Texture2D>("playerSheet"), new Vector2(40, 420), 50, 44);
```

However, I want to check for collision between man and player, but I don't understand how to "join" those two classes to be able to do an if(intersects) in Game1 (if that's the place to do it).

The player rectangle looks like this:

```
playerRect = new Rectangle(currentFrame * frameWidth, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
```

Have I just gone completely "code blind" here, or what? Anyone able to help me out with this, motivation went down after 12 hours of collision testing.

Comment: I might not be understanding the question, but if you can get two Rectangle objects, one for the player and one for the man, can't you just write a function in Game1 that checks if two rectangles intersect? Then you don't have to worry about "joining" the classes, right? Just make a GetRect() function for both the man and the player, and then send those two rects to an Intersects() functin in Game1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, for both of the classes, add a property

```
public Rectangle PositionRectangle { get; private set; }
```

then, in the relevant constructors, you'd need to initiate this property

```
public Man(..., Rectangle rectangle)
{
    PositionRectangle = rectangle;
}

public Player(..., Vector2 position, int width, int height)
{
    PositionRectangle = new rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, width, height);
}
```

You don't need to worry about what frame you're displaying, since this is related to the **source rectangle**, not to the **destination rectangle** (which is what you need to test for collisions).

Then you can test for these collisions easily

```
if(man.PositionRectangle.Intersects(player.PositionRectangle))
{
    //collision logic
}
```

Of course, you'd need to take care to update these rectangles any time you change the positions (or widths and heights if those are changeable)

---

### Slight edit (or a better version)

If you would like to position Man and Player easily without having to worry about how their rectangles are updated, you could set it up like this:

```
class Man
{
    Texture2D _texture;

    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; } 
    public int Height { get; set; }

    public Rectangle PositionRectangle
    {
        get
        {
            return new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, Width, Height);
        }
    }

    public Man(Texture2D texture)
    {
        this._texture = texture;
        this.Width = texture.Width;
        this.Height = texture.Height;
    }

    ... //other man related logic!
}

class Player
{
    Texture2D _texture;
    int _frameCount;
    int _currentFrame;
    //other frame related logic...

    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; } 
    public int Height { get; set; }

    public Rectangle PositionRectangle
    {
        get
        {
            return new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, Width, Height);
        }
    }

    public Rectangle SourceRectangle
    {
        get
        {
            return new Rectangle(Width * _currentFrame, 0, Width, Height);
        }
    }

    public Player(Texture2D texture, int frameWidth, int frameCount)
    {
        this._texture = texture;
        this.Width = frameWidth;
        this.Height = texture.Height;
        this._frameCount = frameCount;
        this._currentFrame = 0;
        //etc...
    }

    ... //other player related logic! such as updating _currentFrame

    public Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
         spriteBatch.Draw(_texture, PositionRectangle, SourceRectangle, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Here I've given you example of how you could make use of property accessors to dynamically generate your relevant rectangles!

You use `PositionRectangle` to determine where your player (or man) will be located on screen, and you use `SourceRectangle` to determine which part of the texture you're gonna draw.

Also, if your man and player widths and heights aren't going to change then you should set their `set` accessors to `private`.

When you need to change the locations, you just set their position property

```
man.Position = new Vector2(100, 100); //i.e.
```

and your collisions and draw logic will automatically use the new rectangles without any further intervention!

Hope you like it!

### Edit2

Relating to source rectangle being public, you only need that if you're drawing these from outside (i.e. `Game1` calls `spriteBatch.Draw(player.Texture, player.PositionRectangle, player.SourceRectangle, Color.White);`).

If you're drawing it like in the example (from the inside), you could just scrap the whole `public Recangle SourceRectangle{...}` thing and just use that rectangle directly in the draw:

```
    public Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
         spriteBatch.Draw(_texture, PositionRectangle, new Rectangle(Width * _currentFrame, 0, Width, Height), Color.White);
    }
```

Comment: This seems like an awesome idea, for sure! I've been implementing your updated ideas now, but as of now, the player character stands completely still (however, the sprite animation works when I use the keys), but it won't move on the screen. I assume this has something to do with frameCount and currentFrame. I also implemented the "Edit2" feature, but I'll have to work on the movement of the character.

Comment: Hmm, that should have no relation to currentFrame (this is only being used for source) - are you certain you are updating the player.Position? try to assign some values to it just to see if the player moves to there

Comment: Haha, what a silly mistake of me. I accidentally used the player.Position (start position) in Game1 update instead of LoadContent. Now it works SPLENDID! However, I try to use simple if-checks to deny "walking off the screen", by using this, but playerPosition "is not a variable" it says. Any ideas on that one? 
if (playerPosition.Y >= 480)
    playerPosition.Y = 480;

Comment: You should just set it like this: `player.Position = new Vector2(player.Position.X, 480);` This is because `player.Position` is of type `Vector2`, which is a value type (`struct`) and not a reference type (`class`).

Comment: But that would set the position of the player to be 480, correct? I try to create some "walls" where the player can not go (such as into the air or outside the viewport). And I can't use `if(player.Position.X >= 480) { player.Position.X = 480; }` since `Position` isn't a variable. Sorry if what you explained is the answer to this, I might misunderstand.

Comment: When you set values to `player.Position`, you should always use another Vector2 (either new one or an existing one). Because of how properties work (how their `set;` works), you cannot directly assign values to sub-properties (in this case `X`) of properties (in this case `Position`) whose type is a value type (in this case `Vector2`). You should always assign a whole value type. Example: `if(player.Position.X >= 480) { player.Position = new Vector2(480, player.Position.Y); }` It would be the equivalent of just assigning 480 to `player.Position.X` because `Y` remains the same! :)

Comment: Hello again! Thanks a bunch, I'll continue to try this when I get back home to the project files. I just noticed that the values won't work with that "method", as it does with the one 4 comments above. I'm able to stop the character from moving out of the screen to the left, but not stop him from moving out of the sidewalk/pavement, as he just teleports around due to the values. Will just have to modify it later :)

Comment: Nvm, works! I just had to play around with the values a bit :). Great, thanks a bunch! Would have used the rest of the week if it wasn't for you :)